# How to use a jQuery api for a slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

I have a jQuery slider in wordpress and I'm trying to create my own previous and next buttons can someone help me with what the code would be for that?

Here is the api info that was given to me:

API Methods:

- Previous Slide: `revapi1.revprev();`
- Next Slide: `revapi1.revnext();`

I guess I need to know how to use those two methods above

Comment: what did you try? What is problem do you have?

Comment: Just make a button that calls one of those functions?

Answer (score 2):

Can you supply a link to the slider? You probably can just use a click event and then fire either the next or prev function based on what arrow is clicked.

So it might be something like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#next").click(function() {
        revapi1.revnext();  
    });
});
```

In that case you could have your next button like so:

```
<button id="next">Next</button>
```

Comment: Here is the test site, I put in your function in the header and the button in the homepage

Comment: I've updated the code in my answer, can you give that a try and see if it works? I take it you've loaded jQuery and the slider plugin before you added that code?

Comment: Still nothing, and I tried both in the footer to make sure the plugin and scripts were loading first

Comment: here is a screen shot of the api info it gives me if it helps https://dl.dropbox.com/u/189987/Screen%20Shot%202012-11-01%20at%204.47.43%20PM.png

Comment: Looks like jQuery is in non-conflict mode so the $ shortcut isn't available so an error is being thrown: "Uncaught TypeError: Property '$' of object [object Window] is not a function"

So you can do as your theme already has done and use this instead so the shortcut will be available.

`jQuery(document).ready(function($){});`

Comment: the plugin developer wasn't much help this is what he sent to me

"if you want to use your navigation, you just put onclick javascript function like"

like what?

Comment: I tried this to no avail

 <script type='text/javascript'>
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
 
 $("#next").click(function() {
        revapi1.revnext();  
    });
 
});
</script>

Comment: this is what they said to do

jQuery('#next').on('click', function() {
                 revapi1.revnext();
                 
});

doesnt work of course

Comment: Is this a paid plugin? If you can link to somewhere to download it if it's on github or a free plugin then please do.

Comment: Here is the plugin (its a paid plugin)

https://dl.dropbox.com/u/189987/codecanyon-2751380-slider-revolution-responsive-wordpress-plugin.zip

Answer (score 0):

Old post, but not a clear answer..

I guess you're using Revolution slider.

```
jQuery('#next').on('click', function() { revapi1.revnext(); });
```

Works perfectly for me. Place the above code in the **'Custom JavaScript'** box (home page of the created slider)

Then place something like this in one of your slides:

```
<button id="next">Next</button>
```

Greetz Bjorn